# Report Max and Min values from columns in excel which also may have "#NULL!"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want Excel to place the maximum and minimum of 4 columns into a high and low column. However, my data include #NULL! for some rows/columns. If I just use MAX or MIN, the Excel populates the #NULL! and errors. How can I do conditional formatting to remove the "#NULL!" as an option that Excel is looking at and still get a high or low?

Data example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE which will ignore errors

Max

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:E2,1)
```

Min

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,B2:E2,1)
```

Comment: Works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `maxifs` and `minifs` function

if the data is in range b1:b6

`=MINIFS(B1:B6, B1:B6,"<>'#NULL'")`

or

`=MAXIFS(B1:B6, B1:B6,"<>'#NULL'")`

should give your result